# How can I use a Transformable attribute as its actual type in a NSManagedObject subclass?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Just starting a project. The data-model file has one entity, which has a single attribute that is Transformable. It's supposed to be a `NS/CGRect`. I had Xcode create corresponding `NSManagedObject` subclass files. For "MyThing.swift", I got:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class MyThing: NSManagedObject {
// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
}
```

And I got a "MyThing+CoreDataProperties.swift":

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension MyThing {
    @NSManaged var myBounds: NSObject?
}
```

I want the property to be an actual `CGRect`, so I need a `NSData <-> NSValue <-> NSRect` conversion chain. I already have "NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformer" as the Name under the Attribute Type in Interface Builder. What do I add (and/or change) to pass `CGRect` values around?

Or do I not do this, and just pass `NSValue`-wrapped `CGRect`s around instead? (I hope that CoreData will take care of any `NSData <-> NSValue` conversions.)

Comment: I went with getting rid of the subclass (and extension) and passing around `NSValue`-wrapped `CGRect`s directly. I still wonder what the best idea is, in case I need to deal with this again.

Answer (score 0):

Because CGRect is not a class but struct i would suggest creating another property which will access the raw variable with proper conversions. And then use only that property.

```
class MyThing {
    var boundsValue : NSValue?

}

extension MyThing {
    var bounds : CGRect {
        get {
            if let value = boundsValue {
                value.CGRectValue()
            }
            return CGRectNull
        }
        set {
            boundsValue =  NSValue(CGRect: newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your transformable type complies to NSCoding, Core Data will take care of the rest for you. I've used `NSAttributedString` in my `NSManagedObjects`, and only changed the CoreData provided `id`-type that was generated at runtime.

If you want to have a property of your own type, i.e. `MyAwesomeObject`, then make sure you implement `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`.

So, for your case, in order to store `CGRects` with CoreData, you would need to wrap them in a class that implements the above mentioned methods. This is because CGRect doesn't comply to the NSCoding protocol, and thus cannot be stored directly as a transformable attribute.

Your other option is of course to store `x`,`y`,`width`,`height` as properties, and either have a transient property wich you compute in `awakeFromFetch` and `awakeFromInsert` or just a convenience method.

Comment: `awakeFromNib`? Do you mean `awakeFromFetch` and `awakeFromSnapshotEvents`?

Comment: Bah. Typo. I meant `awakeFromFetch`. Fixed it now! Thanks for noticing!

Comment: I wrap the `CGRect` values inside `NSValue` objects. I'm wondering what Apple had in mind for implementing Non-Standard Persistent Attributes, like `NSColor` or `NSRect` (via a subclass or otherwise). Maybe there's example code....

Comment: NSValue conforms to NSCoding, so I'm assuming this is what Apple had in mind for non-standard persistent attributes...